# How to write a onecolumn page while using the IEEEtran class?

Tags: page-breaking, two-column, ieeetran, minted

I am writing a document in which I have to add a code in the appendix section. I am using the `IEEEtran` class but it does not help me while adding the code using the `minted` package. Is there a way I can write the complete text using the complete page and allowing it to make break page if necessary?

Here it is a working example:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[]{minted}

    \begin{document}

    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum
    \section{Material}
    \lipsum

    \appendices

    \section{BaudRate}

    \begin{minted}[breaklines,linenos=true,numberblanklines=true]{vhdl}
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
    use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
    use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

    entity BaudRate is
        port(
        RST     :in std_logic;
        CLK     :in std_logic;
        NBaud   :in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);   -- Number of Bauds by second
        FBaud   :out    std_logic                       -- Base frecuency 
        ); 
    end BaudRate;

    architecture simple of BaudRate is

    signal Qp,Qn,NB : std_logic_vector(18 downto 0);

    begin

        COMB: process(NBaud,Qp)
        begin                  

            case NBaud is
                when "0000"=>
                NB<= "1101110111110010001"; -- 110 Bauds
                when "0001"=>       
                NB<= "0101000101100001010"; -- 300 Bauds
                when "0010"=>
                NB<= "0010100010110000101"; -- 600 Bauds
                when "0011"=>
                NB<= "0001010001011000010"; -- 1200 Bauds
                when "0100"=>                    
                NB<= "0000101000101100001"; -- 2400 Bauds
                when "0101"=>
                NB<= "0000010100010110000"; -- 4800 Bauds
                when "0110"=>
                NB<= "0000001010001011000"; -- 9600 Bauds
                when "0111"=>
                NB<= "0000000110110010000"; -- 14400 Bauds
                when "1000"=>
                NB<= "0000000101000101100"; -- 19200 Bauds
                when "1001"=>
                NB<= "0000000010100010110"; -- 38400 Bauds
                when "1010"=>
                NB<= "0000000001101100100"; -- 57600 Bauds
                when "1011"=>                           
                NB<= "0000000000110110010"; -- 115200 Bauds
                when "1100"=>
                NB<= "0000000000110000110"; -- 128000 Bauds
                when "1101"=>
                NB<= "0000000000011000011"; -- 256000 Bauds
                when others=>
                NB<= "0000000000000000000"; -- 0 Bauds

            end case;       

            if(Qp= "0000000000000000000")then
                Qn<= NB;                                         
                FBaud<= '1';
            else 
                Qn<= Qp-1;
                FBaud<= '0';
            end if;

        end process COMB;

        FF: process(RST,CLK)
        begin       
            if(RST='0')then
                Qp <= (others=>'0');                 
            elsif(CLK'event and CLK='1') then
                Qp <= Qn;                 
            end if;
        end process FF;

    end simple;
    \end{minted}

    \section{FsmWrite}

    \begin{minted}[breaklines,linenos=true,numberblanklines=true]{vhdl}
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

    entity FsmWrite is  
        port(
        RST :   in  std_logic;
        CLK :   in  std_logic;
        STR :   in  std_logic;
        FBaud:  in  std_logic;
        EOT :   out std_logic;
        CTRL    :   out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
        );
    end FsmWrite;

    architecture simple of FsmWrite is

    signal Qp, Qn   : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

    begin                                
        COMB: process(Qp,STR,FBaud)
        begin
            case Qp is
                when "0000" =>
                CTRL<= "0000";-- Hold
                EOT<= '1';
                if(STR= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else 
                    Qn<= "0001";
                end if;

                when "0001" =>
                CTRL<= "0000";-- Hold
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '1')then
                    Qn<= "0010";
                else 
                    Qn<= Qp;
                end if;

                when "0010" =>
                CTRL<= "0001";  -- Start
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "0011";
                end if;

                when "0011" =>
                CTRL<= "0010";  -- Bit 0
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "0100";
                end if;

                when "0100" =>
                CTRL<= "0011";  -- Bit 1
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "0101";
                end if;

                when "0101" =>
                CTRL<= "0100";  -- Bit2
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "0110";
                end if;

                when "0110" =>
                CTRL<= "0101";  -- Bit 3 
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "0111";
                end if;

                when "0111" =>
                CTRL<= "0110";  -- Bit 4
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "1000";
                end if;

                when "1000" =>
                CTRL<= "0111";  -- Bit 5 
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "1001";
                end if;

                when "1001" =>
                CTRL<= "1000";  -- Bit 6
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "1010";
                end if;

                when "1010" =>
                CTRL<= "1001";  -- Bit 7 
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "1011";
                end if;

                when "1011" =>
                CTRL<= "1010";  -- Stop 
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "1100";
                end if;     

                when "1100" =>
                CTRL<= "1010";
                EOT<= '0';
                IF (STR='1') THEN
                    Qn <=Qp;
                ELSE
                    Qn<="1101";
                    END IF;

                when others =>   
                CTRL<= "0000";
                EOT<= '1';
                Qn<= "0000";

                end case;

            end process COMB;

            FF: process(RST,CLK)
            begin  
                if(RST='0')then
                    Qp<= "0000";
                elsif(CLK'event and CLK='1')then
                    Qp<= Qn;
                end if;         

            end process;

    end simple;
    \end{minted}

    \end{document}
```

I have already tried to use `figure*` but the problem is that it makes it as a complete picture so I am not able to see the whole code.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\onecolumn` right after `\appendices`; if needed, you can switch back using `\twocolumn` (each of those commands starts a new page):

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[]{minted}

    \begin{document}

    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum
    \section{Material}
    \lipsum

    \appendices

    \section{BaudRate}

    \begin{minted}[breaklines,linenos=true,numberblanklines=true]{vhdl}
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
    use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
    use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

    entity BaudRate is
        port(
        RST     :in std_logic;
        CLK     :in std_logic;
        NBaud   :in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);   -- Number of Bauds by second
        FBaud   :out    std_logic                       -- Base frecuency 
        ); 
    end BaudRate;

    architecture simple of BaudRate is

    signal Qp,Qn,NB : std_logic_vector(18 downto 0);

    begin

        COMB: process(NBaud,Qp)
        begin                  

            case NBaud is
                when "0000"=>
                NB<= "1101110111110010001"; -- 110 Bauds
                when "0001"=>       
                NB<= "0101000101100001010"; -- 300 Bauds
                when "0010"=>
                NB<= "0010100010110000101"; -- 600 Bauds
                when "0011"=>
                NB<= "0001010001011000010"; -- 1200 Bauds
                when "0100"=>                    
                NB<= "0000101000101100001"; -- 2400 Bauds
                when "0101"=>
                NB<= "0000010100010110000"; -- 4800 Bauds
                when "0110"=>
                NB<= "0000001010001011000"; -- 9600 Bauds
                when "0111"=>
                NB<= "0000000110110010000"; -- 14400 Bauds
                when "1000"=>
                NB<= "0000000101000101100"; -- 19200 Bauds
                when "1001"=>
                NB<= "0000000010100010110"; -- 38400 Bauds
                when "1010"=>
                NB<= "0000000001101100100"; -- 57600 Bauds
                when "1011"=>                           
                NB<= "0000000000110110010"; -- 115200 Bauds
                when "1100"=>
                NB<= "0000000000110000110"; -- 128000 Bauds
                when "1101"=>
                NB<= "0000000000011000011"; -- 256000 Bauds
                when others=>
                NB<= "0000000000000000000"; -- 0 Bauds

            end case;       

            if(Qp= "0000000000000000000")then
                Qn<= NB;                                         
                FBaud<= '1';
            else 
                Qn<= Qp-1;
                FBaud<= '0';
            end if;

        end process COMB;

        FF: process(RST,CLK)
        begin       
            if(RST='0')then
                Qp <= (others=>'0');                 
            elsif(CLK'event and CLK='1') then
                Qp <= Qn;                 
            end if;
        end process FF;

    end simple;
    \end{minted}

    \section{FsmWrite}

    \begin{minted}[breaklines,linenos=true,numberblanklines=true]{vhdl}
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

    entity FsmWrite is  
        port(
        RST :   in  std_logic;
        CLK :   in  std_logic;
        STR :   in  std_logic;
        FBaud:  in  std_logic;
        EOT :   out std_logic;
        CTRL    :   out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
        );
    end FsmWrite;

    architecture simple of FsmWrite is

    signal Qp, Qn   : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

    begin                                
        COMB: process(Qp,STR,FBaud)
        begin
            case Qp is
                when "0000" =>
                CTRL<= "0000";-- Hold
                EOT<= '1';
                if(STR= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else 
                    Qn<= "0001";
                end if;

                when "0001" =>
                CTRL<= "0000";-- Hold
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '1')then
                    Qn<= "0010";
                else 
                    Qn<= Qp;
                end if;

                when "0010" =>
                CTRL<= "0001";  -- Start
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "0011";
                end if;

                when "0011" =>
                CTRL<= "0010";  -- Bit 0
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "0100";
                end if;

                when "0100" =>
                CTRL<= "0011";  -- Bit 1
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "0101";
                end if;

                when "0101" =>
                CTRL<= "0100";  -- Bit2
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "0110";
                end if;

                when "0110" =>
                CTRL<= "0101";  -- Bit 3 
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "0111";
                end if;

                when "0111" =>
                CTRL<= "0110";  -- Bit 4
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "1000";
                end if;

                when "1000" =>
                CTRL<= "0111";  -- Bit 5 
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "1001";
                end if;

                when "1001" =>
                CTRL<= "1000";  -- Bit 6
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "1010";
                end if;

                when "1010" =>
                CTRL<= "1001";  -- Bit 7 
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "1011";
                end if;

                when "1011" =>
                CTRL<= "1010";  -- Stop 
                EOT<= '0';
                if(FBaud= '0')then
                    Qn<= Qp;
                else
                    Qn<= "1100";
                end if;     

                when "1100" =>
                CTRL<= "1010";
                EOT<= '0';
                IF (STR='1') THEN
                    Qn <=Qp;
                ELSE
                    Qn<="1101";
                    END IF;

                when others =>   
                CTRL<= "0000";
                EOT<= '1';
                Qn<= "0000";

                end case;

            end process COMB;

            FF: process(RST,CLK)
            begin  
                if(RST='0')then
                    Qp<= "0000";
                elsif(CLK'event and CLK='1')then
                    Qp<= Qn;
                end if;         

            end process;

    end simple;
    \end{minted}

    \end{document}
```

[image]